# Hide/Simply close Jdialog on click of X

Tags: java, swing, applet, jdialog

I am trying to set the default close operation on close of Jdialog. However, my progressbar code is overriding the closing event. I wasn't sure of a place to write the

```
dialog.setVisible(true); and  dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
```

statements.

Below is my `init() method` and and my `Jdialog`. 
Please review and suggest.

```
  @Override
        public void init() {

            dialog = new JDialog(new JFrame(), "Progress", true);
            dialog.setSize(300, 75);
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
            }

        public void updateProgressBar(final int progress) {
        dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        for (i = 0; i <= 100; i = i + 1) {

         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
         progressBar.setValue(progress);
         dialog.setVisible(true);
        }
        });
    }
    if(progressBar.getValue()==100){
    dialog.dispose();
    System.out.println("File uploaded successfully!");
}
```

What is not working here is - the `dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation().` 
Why is it not working is - because I have the `dialog.setVisible(true)` in my `updateProgessBar()` method, to show the updating progress of my fileupload.

Each time there is a progress, the `dialog.setVisible becomes true`, thereyby overriding the `setDefaultCloseOperation` written in the `init() method`. 
If I place the dialog.setVisible(true) present in my updateProgressBar() elsewhere, the jdialog progress bar would not update and appear as expected.

So, my question is how would I adjust these two statements within the code, so that, I will also be able to perform the default close operation ?

Comment: Could you post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and better an better explain what's not working.. _after_ you post the MCTRE.

Comment: Thank you, updated my question to provide better clarity.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want to display a `JDialog` with a Progress bar in it. Swing has an own class to do that, `ProgressMonitor`. Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of ProgressMonitor]

If that is what you need, Javadoc is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitor.html), sample/tutorial is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html#monitors).

Comment: Sure, I had this out of the way and was lost in working with Jdialog. I can re-do the action using progressMonitor and see how it goes. Thanks for bringing me back to track :)

Answer (score 0):

To handle the klick of the 'X' (as well as pressing Alt+F4 on Windows or closing the window in the Task Manager), you can add a `WindowListener`: `dialog.addWindowListener(...);`. Because `WindowListener` is an interface with a lot of methods you might not need, you can also use a `WindowAdapter`.

Instead of explainging, I will show you two samples:

```
dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {
    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {
        //User clicked 'X'
    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent arg0) {
        //Window is closed, now you can free resources if you need.
    }

    @Override
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent arg0) {
    }
});
```

Second sample:

```
dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {
        //User clicked 'X'
    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent arg0) {
        //Window is closed, now you can free resources if you need.
    }
});
```

As you can see, if you use `WindowAdapter`, you can just pick the methods that you need.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I have already tried the windowClosing event, but that hasn't worked, as I mentioned, my dialog.setVisible(true) updates each time, there is a file upload progress. This is preventing the event from happening.